# passing in table name as plsql parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to write a function to return the row count of a table whose name is passed in as a variable. Here's my code:

```
create or replace function get_table_count (table_name IN varchar2)
  return number
is
  tbl_nm varchar(100) := table_name;
  table_count number;
begin
  select count(*)
  into table_count
  from tbl_nm;
  dbms_output.put_line(table_count);
  return table_count;
end;
```

I get this error:

```
FUNCTION GET_TABLE_COUNT compiled
Errors: check compiler log
Error(7,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(9,8): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I understand that `tbl_nm` is being interpreted as a value and not a reference and I'm not sure how to escape that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL:

```
create or replace function get_table_count (table_name IN varchar2)
  return number
is
  table_count number;
begin
  execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || table_name into table_count;
  dbms_output.put_line(table_count);
  return table_count;
end;
```

There is also an indirect way to get number of rows (using system views):

```
create or replace function get_table_count (table_name IN varchar2)
  return number
is
  table_count number;
begin
  select num_rows
    into table_count
    from user_tables
   where table_name = table_name;

  return table_count;
end;
```

The second way works only if you had gathered statistics on table before invoking this function.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - Oracle provides the DBMS_ASSERT package so we can easily handle SQL injection attacks. The problem with the second approach is that its dependence on statistics means the returned value may be inaccurate or misleading, unless we gather stats on the table immediately before running the count which is (a) time-consuming (b) potentially destabilising to ongoing performance.