# Pass table as parameter in PL/SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Please excuse any poorly phrased questions as I have very little experience with PL/SQL and Oracle. However, I am currently unaware of how to pass a table as a parameter. Currently, this procedure outputs the one entry that matches the designated inputs. For instance, if trade product = a, trade region = c, counter party region = b, trade desk = d, trade legal entity = e, hedge product = f and hedge legal entity = g, then it returns this unique combination. However, I'd like to have the ability to assign multiple values to each parameter and return all the results. For instance, based on the previous example, if I designate that hedge legal entity = g or h, then i'd like to see 2 entries -"a,c,b,d,e,f,g" AND "a,c,b,d,e,f,h". I believe this is done by changing my parameters types to tables of varchar2s instead of a single varchar2. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SOX_SCOPING.BM_ENTIRE_TABLE_ARRAY_PARAMS (
trade_product in varchar2
, trade_region in varchar2
, counterparty_region in varchar2
, trade_desk in varchar2
, trade_legal_entity in varchar2
, hedge_product in varchar2
, hedge_legal_entity in varchar2
, out_cursor out sys_refcursor) IS

BEGIN

open out_cursor for 
SELECT D.PRODUCTS AS TRADE_PRODUCTS, D.TRADER_REGION, D.REGION, D.DESK AS TRADE_DESK, D.LEGAL_ENTITY AS TRADE_LEGAL_ENTITY,F.PRODUCTS AS HEDGE_PRODUCTS, F.LEGAL_ENTITY AS HEDGE_LEGAL_ENTITY
FROM
(SELECT C.*, BM_LEGAL_ENTITY.LEGAL_ENTITY
FROM
    (SELECT B.*, BM_DESK.DESK 
    FROM
        (SELECT *
        FROM 
            (SELECT  BM_PRODUCTS.*,BM_TRADER_REGION.REGION AS TRADER_REGION
            FROM SOX_SCOPING.BM_PRODUCTS
            CROSS JOIN SOX_SCOPING.BM_TRADER_REGION)
        CROSS JOIN SOX_SCOPING.BM_COUNTERPARTY_REGION) B
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SOX_SCOPING.BM_DESK
    ON B.PRODUCTS = BM_DESK.DESK_TO_PRODUCT) C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN BM_LEGAL_ENTITY
ON C.DESK = BM_LEGAL_ENTITY.LEGAL_ENTITY_TO_DESK) D
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT E.*,BM_LEGAL_ENTITY.LEGAL_ENTITY
FROM
    (SELECT BM_PRODUCTS.*,BM_DESK.DESK
    FROM SOX_SCOPING.BM_PRODUCTS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SOX_SCOPING.BM_DESK
    ON BM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS = BM_DESK.DESK_TO_PRODUCT) E
LEFT OUTER JOIN BM_LEGAL_ENTITY
ON E.DESK = BM_LEGAL_ENTITY.LEGAL_ENTITY_TO_DESK) F
where
d.products in (trade_product)    
and D.TRADER_REGION in (trade_region)
and D.REGION in (counterparty_region)
and D.DESK in (trade_desk)
and D.LEGAL_ENTITY in (trade_legal_entity)
and F.PRODUCTS in (hedge_product)
and F.LEGAL_ENTITY in (hedge_legal_entity)
ORDER BY TRADE_PRODUCTS, TRADER_REGION,REGION,TRADE_DESK,HEDGE_PRODUCTS,HEDGE_LEGAL_ENTITY;


   EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   NULL;
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
   -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
   RAISE;
 END BM_ENTIRE_TABLE_ARRAY_PARAMS;
```

/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing in table name as plsql parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592366/passing-in-table-name-as-plsql-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would write it if I had to create a procedure with a variable for the table name and an OUT parameter as SYS_REFCURSOR. Hopefully you can adapt it to your code.

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE PROC_ONE(vstablename VARCHAR2, 
                                     c1          OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) 
IS 
sqlstmt VARCHAR2(255); 
BEGIN 
sqlstmt := 'select * from ' 
           ||vstablename; 

OPEN c1 FOR sqlstmt; 
END;
```