# PL/SQL : How to accept input inside procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, parameter-passing

I have the below procedure in which I need to accept the schema name. The procedure will
be executed only in that schema.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure() AS
BEGIN
FCSCHEMA VARCHAR2(20) := :SCHEMA; --How to accept the parameter and pass it on to below code.


   result := FCSCHEMA.my_package.my_function(p_param1);

END;
/
```

Currenly I am getting `PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'SCHEMA'` error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing in table name as plsql parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592366/passing-in-table-name-as-plsql-parameter). The same way works for anything - schema name, table name, column name, etc.

Comment: @Dmitry, calling a function dynamically is fairly different to selecting a table.

Comment: Is the schema something you are trying to specify once at the point you compile the procedure, or something that can change each time the procedure is called?

Comment: @AlexPoole It is once at the point of compiling the procedure.

Comment: Then making the procedure body dynamic doesn't really make sense; either change the procedure body before compilation to hard-code the schema you want to refer to (rather than hard-codeing it in a variable!?), or if you run this through e.g. SQL\*Plus you can use a substitution variable to provide the schema name during compilation?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit "fairly different"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure() AS

FCSCHEMA VARCHAR2(20) := 'SCHEMA'; 
BEGIN

   execute immediate 'BEGIN :res := '||FCSCHEMA ||'.my_package.my_function(:p_param1); END;' 
        USING OUT result, IN p_param1;

END;
/
```

Comment: Semicolon after `IN p_param1` is required.